# Changing www prefix in General Settings and Interior Links

Tags: site-url

This may be the most redundant/dumbest question known to man, but if I go into Wordpress' General Settings and modify my Site Url to include a `www`, so

```
http://mysite.com
```

becomes

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

do I need to run a MySQL query to find/replace my image sources, my interior page links, etc?  They all currently point to an address without the `www`, will this cause an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could help you, just change mysite.com and www.mysite.com and go to phpMyadmin run that Sql code:

```
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_author_url = REPLACE(comment_author_url, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_users SET user_email = REPLACE(user_email, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
UPDATE wp_users SET user_url = REPLACE(user_url, 'mysite.com', 'www.mysite.com');
```

OR

You can use [that](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-site-url-migration-generator/) simple tool it will generate it for you. If you are using different Table Prefix just change `wp_` with your table prefix.

Comment: Please explain your code in human terms and explain why you think it should solve the problem.

Comment: @RCNeil want mysite.com to www.mysite.com? This code just will replace it.

Comment: Do you know if this covers ALL fields that use the site url setting?  I agree that you should elaborate a bit on your answer, although it was helpful.  Is it necessary?  Is it everything?  Thank you.

Comment: It will help you. Go to your phpMyadmin panel and run this sql code. it will change your old url(mysite.com) to new url(www.mysite.com). And I updated my answer check out. I hope, that help you. @RCNeil